# Expressjs: How to catch form data using POST method?

Tags: node.js, express

Guys.

I'm currently building a rather large project and I want to know which the best tool that I can use to catch form data using the POST method. The form is a 'sigin' and 'login' form

I read about 'body-parser' and 'busboy', but I'm a noob and I don't know which is the best choice

Comment: express would be better with body-parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use body-parser.

```
const app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Place this before the declaration of your route in your main file. Also - ensure that the form data elements you will be submitting have a name attribute. If there is no name attribute, you will not see the data come through. 
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I am also new to express but i learned that you dont need to add **body-parser** as express comes with it by default now

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
```

Answer (score 0):

A good one is [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable), and it has an Express version: [express-formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-formidable. Very handy for multipart form data.

That said, a "best choice" would be hard to come by. Likely the first one you get working will be the best! ; )